# Accessing to attributes of html tags inside knockoutjs template

Tags: jquery, css, knockout.js

I have a template like this:

```html
<script id="notesTemplate" type="text/html">
<li class="Note">
    <div class="NoteDate" data-bind="style: { backgroundColor: background, color: color}">
            <span data-bind="text: date"></span>
        </div>
        <div class="NoteRight" data-bind="style: { backgroundColor: background, color: color}">
            <div class="NoteContent">
                <span data-bind="text: content"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="line" data-bind="style: { borderColor: color}"></div>
            <div class="NoteCategory" data-bind="style: { color: color}">
                <span data-bind="text: category"></span>
            </div>
        </div>
</li>
</script>
```

As you see, I create a simple list with notes (I set some css styles because every note item have its own bg and color but, is this the right way?) but:

I want to set the `NoteDate` div with height equal to the `NoteRight` div. I'm actually doing that in JS:

```
$(function () {
    ko.applyBindings(new viewModel());

    $(".Note").each(function (index, element) {
        var date = $(element).find(".NoteDate");
        var note = $(element).find(".NoteRight");

        date.height(note.height());
    });
});
```

But this is kinda slow because the notes are retrieved using Ajax and I have to do that call with `async: false` or the notes will not be fetched before the "each" runs.

So: It's possible to "translate" that code to the template? I tried something like:

```html
<div class="NoteDate" 
     data-bind="style: { backgroundColor: background, 
                         color: color, height: $('.NoteRight').height() }">
```

But that doesn't work.

After even some more fiddling around, I have this function now (`afterRender`):

```
this.updateNotesLayout = function (elements) {
    var date = $(elements).find(".NoteDate");
    var note = $(elements).find(".NoteRight");
    alert(date.height());
    alert(note.height());
    date.height(note.height());
    alert(date.height());
}
```

But the date and note height is 0, but in the old example, the height was correct on both cases.

Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest option to run code against elements rendered by a template is to use the `afterRender` callback of the template binding.

http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/template-binding.html#note_4_using_the__option

This will allow you to run code on your new nodes.  In a foreach situation this runs for each item.

Comment: Thank you, what I needed but Im getting a problem, I edited my question :)

Comment: During afterRender, the nodes aren't actually in the DOM yet, so you might be hitting a timing issue.  One workaround to this is to perform your action in a setTimeout like:  setTimeout(function() { yourcode; }, 0)

Comment: Can you update your answer with an example of my code with the timeout? Im trying buy Im really new to web dev. NVM, I got it